# Override Spring Authentication provider

Tags: java, maven, spring-security, selenium-webdriver, tomcat7

I am using maven to run an instance of tomcat to do some integration tests. I am using the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` artifact. When tomcat starts it loads a bunch of Spring configuration  files beans into the context as a result of this chunk of my `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:mspWebManager-root.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Within the configuration is this xml defining the authentication provider for Spring Security:

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">        
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />         
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

In my integration test, I would like to override that authentication provider to basically allow all requests through.

**My Current Attempt:**

I have in my test case this code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/mpsWebManager-test-context.xml",
            "classpath:/mspWebManager-security-test-context.xml"})
public class SeleniumIT {....test cases....}
```

Inside of `mspWebManager-security-test-context.xml` is this xml:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceMock"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

But, when I make requests inside of my test case (I am using Selenium btw to make the requests), the `preauthAuthProvider` defined previously is always getting used. **Is there a way to override this?**

I am relatively new to Spring and tomcat so I am open to suggestions on the best way to do this. Another thing I have tried is setting up a maven test profile to try and get tomcat to use a different web.xml file, but this wasn't working.

Thanks